# Mysql: Joining 3 tables with more than one 'where'?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to join one table to another on one condition, and then the table to another table on another condition. Can you do this and if so what is the correct syntax? I've been trying this but it doesn't work:

```
$check = $members->prepare("select users.fname, users.lname, groups.groupid, attributes.max 
    from users 
    JOIN groups 
         on users.user_id = groups.userid 
    where groups.userid = ? 
    LEFT JOIN attributes 
         on users.user_id = attributes.userid 
    where attributes.groupid = ?");
$check->bind_param('ss', $_SESSION['token'][1], $which_group);
$check->execute();
```

cheers.

Comment: You can only have one `WHERE` clause, but you can put multiple conditions in there. See the documentation of the database you use how to write that, especially in the context of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use........  `AND`

```
$check = $members->prepare("select users.fname, users.lname, groups.groupid, attributes.max 
    FROM users 
    JOIN groups 
         ON users.user_id = groups.userid 
         AND groups.userid = ? 
    LEFT JOIN attributes 
         ON users.user_id = attributes.userid 
         AND attributes.groupid = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

The test for `attributes.groupid` must be part of the join conditions on the LEFT JOIN. Attempting to test this condition in the WHERE clause would force the LEFT JOIN to behave as if it were an INNER JOIN.

```
select users.fname, users.lname, groups.groupid, attributes.max 
    from users 
        JOIN groups 
            on users.user_id = groups.userid 
        LEFT JOIN attributes 
            on users.user_id = attributes.userid 
                and attributes.groupid = ?
    where groups.userid = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If the condition you're referring to is a literal and not in any way related to the joined table, combine them on one where clause.

```
select users.fname, users.lname, groups.groupid, attributes.max
from users
   JOIN groups 
        on users.user_id = groups.userid 
    LEFT JOIN attributes 
        on users.user_id = attributes.userid 
where groups.userid = ? and attributes.groupid = ?
```